# How to call a stored procedure from Spring

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, stored-procedures

How do I insert data into a table via a stored procedure in spring?

Can anyone please refer an example.  My stored procedure has some auto generated values.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_employee_insert]
    @full_name varchar(75),@gender varchar(6), @department varchar(25), _
    @position varchar(50),@salary float
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO employees (full_name,gender,department,position,salary)
    VALUES  (@full_name,@gender,@department,@position,@salary)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should add an `EntityManager` to access the database:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Also you should add the `StoredProcedureQuery` interface to your class, this way you can use several methods to interact with the **stored procedures** such as `registerStoredProcedureParameter`, `setParameter`, `execute` among others.

Assuming that you have a `Person` entity with the attributes mentioned in your stored procedure, you can take this snippet code as example:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import your.entity.package.Person;

@Service
public class StoredProcedureManagement {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void callStoredProcedure(Person person) {

        // invoking your sp
        StoredProcedureQuery spInsert = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("dbo.usp_employee_insert");

        // registring sp parameters
        spInsert.registerStoredProcedureParameter("full_name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        spInsert.registerStoredProcedureParameter("gender", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        spInsert.registerStoredProcedureParameter("department", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        spInsert.registerStoredProcedureParameter("position", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        spInsert.registerStoredProcedureParameter("salary", Float.class, ParameterMode.IN);

        // setting the parameters
        spInsert.setParameter("full_name", person.getFullName());
        spInsert.setParameter("gender", person.getGender());
        spInsert.setParameter("department", person.getDepartment());
        spInsert.setParameter("position", person.getPosition());
        spInsert.setParameter("salary", person.getSalary());

        // executing the sp
        spInsert.execute();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
public class UspEmployeeInsert extends StoredProcedure {

    private final String NAME = "usp_employee_insert";

    public UspEmployeeInsert(DataSource dataSource) {

        setDataSource(dataSource);
        setSql(NAME);

        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("full_name", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("gender", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("department", Types.DATE));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("position", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("salary", Types.FLOAT));

        compile();
    }

    public void execute(
        String fullName,
        String gender,
        Date deparment,
        String position,
        Float salary){

        final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>(5);
        parameters.put("full_name", fullName);
        parameters.put("gender", gender);
        parameters.put("department", deparment);
        parameters.put("position", position);
        parameters.put("salary", salary);

        execute(parameters);
    }
}
```

Or you could do this:

```
@Repository
public class UspEmployeeRepository {

    private final String NAME = "usp_employee_insert";
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public UspEmployeeRepository(DataSource dataSource) {

        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void insert(
        String fullName,
        String gender,
        Date deparment,
        String position,
        Float salary){

        jdbcTemplate.update(
            "{ call usp_employee_insert(?,?,?,?,?) }",
            fullName,gender,deparment,position,salary
        );
    }
}
```